# Braintree Drop In Apple Pay crashing

Tags: ios, braintree, applepay

Presenting PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController always results in a total crash with pointing to my AppDelegate: **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

```
let vc = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest) as PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?

if vc != nil{

    vc!.delegate = self

    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}else{
    print("error")
}
```

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

btw.: I am checking .canMakePayments() if it is available first.

The exception message is

> Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

Comment: What is the message associated with the exception?

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried to catch the exception with a breakpoint ( po $arg1 ) and got: Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

objc[63935]: pthread_rwlock_rdlock failed (11)

Comment: Right, so you have locked your app into landscape mode, but Apple Pay must be presented in portrait mode. Make sure your app allows portrait orientations.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. Yeah. I really expected Apple Pay to work in landscape mode too. But at least I've learned something new about debugging ( po $arg1 ). I really don't want to support portrait mode for my app. I need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` is presented in portrait orientation so that FaceID functions correctly.

You are getting an exception as you have only landscape options selected under 'Device Orientation' in your project.  You need to add portrait to this list.

[image]

You can limit the rest of your view controllers to landscape orientation if that is what you want.